# How to Word Wrap ion-input in Ionic 2+?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, ionic2

how do I word wrap an `ion-input` component in **Ionic 2**?

This works:

```
<ion-item text-wrap>
    <div>A really realll really really loooooooonnngg text.</div>
</ion-item>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<ion-item text-wrap>
    <ion-input
    type="text"
    id="commuterLocation"
    name="commuterLocation"
    readonly=true
    placeholder="Enter your location"
    (focus)="onCommuterLocationFocus()"
    [(ngModel)]="_commuterLocation.description"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

**Edit 1:**
When I use the `text-wrap` directive on an `ion-item` with regular `html` elements, the elements' contents wrap as expected. But the input text of `ion-input` doesn't... how do I resolve this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why you don't use an ion-texarea?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? can you add a screenshot or something else? is it only for styling? because the input in the ion-item wont go further than the screen resolution goes.

Comment: @SergioEscudero hmm... going to try that...

Comment: Ok. It was good

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Resolved this by using `ion-textarea` over `ion-input`.

```
<ion-item text-wrap>
    <ion-textarea
    type="text"
    id="commuterLocation"
    name="commuterLocation"
    readonly=true
    placeholder="Enter your location"
    (focus)="onCommuterLocationFocus()"
    [(ngModel)]="_commuterLocation.description"></ion-textarea>
</ion-item>
```